# Java for loop doesnt execute

Tags: for-loop, bluetooth, java

I am having problems with my remote device discovery code for bluetooth scanning. 
It scans, and prints the MAC addresses if i uncomment the "system.out.print(devicesDiscovered);

But i want to be able to extract each MAC address from the Vector and place it in a String.

I have two differant FOR loops to do this, but neither of them seem to be executing.

Code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Vector;
import javax.bluetooth.*;

public class BluetoothDeviceDiscovery {

    public static final Vector/*<RemoteDevice>*/ devicesDiscovered = new Vector();

    public static void main() throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        final Object inquiryCompletedEvent = new Object();

        devicesDiscovered.clear();

        final DiscoveryListener listener = new DiscoveryListener() {

            public void deviceDiscovered(RemoteDevice btDevice, DeviceClass cod) {              
                devicesDiscovered.addElement(btDevice);

                //
                String testingAgain = devicesDiscovered.toString();
                System.out.println("What?? : " + testingAgain);

                /*
                * As far as i know, the following two FOR loops do the same thing
                * But both of them are not being executed...
                */

                //Its not executing this...
                for(int i=0; i< devicesDiscovered.size(); i++) {
                    System.out.println("test if this gets output");
                    String test = (String) devicesDiscovered.elementAt(i);
                    System.out.println("Test: " + test);
                }                
                //Its not executing this....
                for(int i=0; i> ((List) btDevice).size(); i++){
                    System.out.println("test if this gets output 1");
                    String testing = (String) devicesDiscovered.toString();
                    System.out.print("Test1: " + testing);
                }
                //Prints the MAC addresses [macaddress, macaddress, macaddress, etc]
               // System.out.println(devicesDiscovered);



                /*
                 * Now need to extract each macaddress from devicesDiscovered
                 * and convert from a Vector to a String
                 */
            }

            public void inquiryCompleted(int discType) {
                System.out.println("Device Inquiry completed!");
                synchronized(inquiryCompletedEvent){
                    inquiryCompletedEvent.notifyAll();
                }
            }

            public void serviceSearchCompleted(int transID, int respCode) {
            }

            public void servicesDiscovered(int transID, ServiceRecord[] servRecord) {
            }
        };

        synchronized(inquiryCompletedEvent) {
            boolean started = LocalDevice.getLocalDevice().getDiscoveryAgent().startInquiry(DiscoveryAgent.GIAC, listener);
            if (started) {
                System.out.println("wait for device inquiry to complete...");
                inquiryCompletedEvent.wait();
                System.out.println(devicesDiscovered.size() +  " device(s) found");
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Can anyone spot any reason(s) as to why these two for loops are not working?

Thanks a lot
- Ryan

Comment: What is the output of your program? I would say that the devices list is empty, but without output I cannot affirm that.

Comment: on a side note, stop using `Vector`, which belongs to yesteryears' API.

Comment: The output is simply [MACADDRESS] but none of the print statements within the For-loops print...which tells me the loops dont execute. Do you suggest i try to use a string Array instead of Vectors then??

Comment: Sorry, but I can't help you! I'm getting the `BluetoothStack not initalized` exception while running your code! And I cannot figure out the way to solve it.

Comment: It was a real pain for me to set it up actually. Im using Ubuntu, and have Bluecove-gpl.jar attached in Eclipse.

Comment: @Sandro: Thanks for the edit proposal, but corrections to the OP's code should be in comments or questions - don't make substantial changes to it in a question edit, as this may cover up problems that the OP is having.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The execution of your code in my machine is the following:

> BlueCove version 2.1.0 on bluez
>
> wait for device inquiry to complete...
>
> What?? : [...]
>
> test if this gets output
>
> Test: ...
>
> Device Inquiry completed!
>
> 1 device(s) found
>
> BlueCove stack shutdown completed

With the following `for` loop:

```
for(int i=0; i< devicesDiscovered.size(); i++) 
{
    System.out.println("test if this gets output");
    String test = (String) devicesDiscovered.elementAt(i).toString();
    System.out.println("Test: " + test);
}
```

I've noticed that you were testing which one of the `for` loops was generating the output that you wanted. I can say that the above one works but the second generates an exception. You are trying to cast a `RemoteDevice` object to a `List` and iterate through it (`for(int i=0; i < ((List) btDevice).size(); i++)`). That's the reason for not working and therefore the exception.

Answer (score 6):

In this line

```
//Its not executing this....
for(int i=0; i > ((List) btDevice).size(); i++) {
```

You have turned the `>` the wrong way... try

```
for(int i=0; i < ((List) btDevice).size(); i++) {
```

instead.

(The reason it doesn't iterate, is because the initial value, 0, is not greater than the size of the list!)

---

In your first loop:

```
//Its not executing this...
for(int i=0; i< devicesDiscovered.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println("test if this gets output");
```

it must be the case that `devicesDiscovered` is empty. I suggest you do

```
System.out.println(devicesDiscovered.size());
```

before the loop to debug.

Comment: Sorry i totally forgot about that - I had changed that just to see if there was any differance. It doesnt work which ever way round that is...
What im expecting is that it prints the MAC address for each Vector Index. but at the moment, it doesnt like it

Comment: When adding the print size statement, it tells me it has a size of 1, therfore 1 MAC address. I currently have 3 bluetooth devices im testing with. and each time, it prints a differant one of the three MAC address. 
I think i should have a complete re-think